# What is the correct way to test this code using MOQ?

Tags: c#, moq

I have the following method:

```
    public void MoveChannelUp(string channelName)
    {
        var liveChannels = _repository.GetChannels<LiveChannel>();

        var channels = GetModifiedChannelsList(channelName, liveChannels);

        _repository.SaveChannels(channels);
    }
```

I want to set up an expectation on the SaveChannels() call so that the correct channels parameter is passed in.

I tried :

```
   channelsRepository.Setup(x => x.SaveChannels(reorderedChannels));
```

where reorderedChannels is what I expect the GetModifiedChannelsList() call will return and but I got Mock verification exception (probably due to reorderedChannels is not the same object as channels???)

So it is GetModifiedChanneslsList() which I really want to test (I know I can use reflection to test this)

So how do I test the correct channels list is passed to SaveChannels()?

Comment: I'm fairly new to Moq also. Maybe you can try the Moq `It` helpers, I tried that, see an example here: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2012/02/primer-on-unit-testing-with-moq.html

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this (I assume there is a type called `Channel` and the parameter for SaveChannels is `List<Channel>`; substitute with the actual):

```
var expectedChannels = new List<Channel> { new Channel() }; // set up expected channels here

var channelsRepo = new Mock<IChannelsRepository>();

// perform your unit test using channelsRepo here, for example:

channelsRepo.Object.SaveChannels(new List<Channel> { new Channel() });

channelsRepo.Verify(x => x.SaveChannels(It.Is<List<Channel>>(l => l.SequenceEqual(expectedChannels)))); // will throw an exception if call to SaveChannels wasn't made, or the List of Channels params did not match the expected.
```

What this code does is verify that the `SaveChannels` method is called at least once with the right list of channels. If that does not happen, `Verify` will throw an exception and your unit test will fail as expected.

Comment: Thanks, I tried .CallBack() and that seems to work but I like your solution as it is cleaner to follow. Btw, shouldn't channelsRepo.Object.SaveChannels(new List<Channel> { new Channel() }); bet channelsRepo.Object.SaveChannels(exceptedChannels});??

Comment: @JD: Maybe you've already done this, but you also have to make sure that `Equals` (and thus `ToHashCode`) is implemented on `Channel`.  Otherwise I think you'll get reference equality rather than logical equality.

Comment: @JD: In your actual unit test, you won't explicitly call channelsRepo.Object.SaveChannels; it's implied that your MoveChannelUp method will call that, specifying the channels resulting from GetModifiedChannelsList. After all, the point of this is for you to test that GetModifiedChannelsList is returning the list of channels you expect.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham Nice one, forgot about that...I was too focused on the Moq api, I'll give it a go.